# Sencha touch 2 - Memory management - destroying tab panels

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to ensure my app is handling memory correctly, i have it destroying panels on the 'erased' event, but when i do this to tab panels, it obviously removes them from the tabbar.

What strategy is best for handling memory and when tab panels are out of view?

Comment: I don't get why would you want to destroy your tab panels but still have them in your tab bar ?

Comment: Heyyyyyy Bohboh...You can't destroy your panels and have them too.

Comment: I realise that I cannot destroy and still have them, i was wondering if there was a technique for handling memory when tabs are out of view. E.g. remove from the DOM yet keep them in memory, therefore have less in the DOM for ST2 to work with. Just an idea..

Comment: Do check this out too, it looks helpful: https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.tab.OptimizedTab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can actually be done, and it's a great technique but it's a bit difficult to implement.  First off you need to not use the tabpanel.  You need to create your own version of the tabpanel.  The strategy is this:

- Create a container with layout: 'card'.  This container will hold your panels.
- Dock a toolbar to the bottom of this container and fill the items array with different tabs
- In your controller add 'control' properties to your config object for each of the tabs in the toolbar and listen for the tab 'tap' event;
- On tab 'tap' you will render each view to your container.
- Add an 'activeitemchange' event listener to your container and destroy the oldCard.

I put together some boilerplate awhile back when Sencha Touch 2 was in pre release.  The concepts are still applicable, though some of the code needs to be upgraded.  Take a look here:

https://github.com/ARolek/Sencha-Touch-2.0-MVC-Boilerplate

This is not an easy concept, so let me know what needs clarification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wish i had seen this earlier, my app is too far gone to change, but will implement in my next one. Thanks!